# Dynamic Xml parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xml-parsing

I am working with the project in which all the user data are depend on Web service.
The web service developer sends  xml as a response of my soap-request.

In some case web service developer generating xml from different class for Same Web service.
In that case xml is generated with different Element tags. Here **Login** is my Webservice and getting two different response in different case

```
//============Response 1====================Success========================================
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://xyzs.com xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
          <LoginUserResponse xmlns="http://xyz.co/">
             <LoginUserResult>   —————————————————————>StartElement
                <ArrayOfUserLoginComplexType xmlns="">
                   <UserLoginComplexType>      ——————————————————————>RowElement              
                      <UserId>1</UserId>
                      <Role>User</Role>
                      <UserName>abc</UserName>
                      <Email>user@xyz.com</Email>
                      <ZipCode>0</ZipCode>
                      <IsRead>false</IsRead>
                      <IsWrite>false</IsWrite>
                      <IsDelete>false</IsDelete>
                      <NoOfUser>0</NoOfUser>
                      <isPediaPurchased>false</isPediaPurchased>
                      <isPaymentDone>false</isPaymentDone>
                   </UserLoginComplexType>
                </ArrayOfUserLoginComplexType>
             </LoginUserResult>
          </LoginUserResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

//============Response 2======================Failuer=======================================
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
          <LoginUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
             <LoginUserResult>   —————————————————————>StartElement
                <ctMessageMst xmlns=“”>————————————————————  > RowElement
                   <MessageID>13</MessageID>
                   <TitleName>Xyz</TitleName>
                   <ProductID>0</ProductID>
                   <MessageText>Hi there</MessageText>
                   <MessageType>E</MessageType>
                   <Date>2014-07-15</Date>
                </ctMessageMst>
             </LoginUserResult>
          </LoginUserResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

//--------XML Parser Code-----------------------------------------------------------------
      - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
        {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetAllMessageListResult"]) {
             row_elementName=@"ctMessageMst";
             [self CreateDictionary];       
        }   
        else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"LoginUserResult"]) {        
            row_elementName=@"UserLoginComplexType";  //Hardcode condition that i have implemented
            [self CreateDictionary];
        }.....
```

In my project I have done hardcode for Rowelement ,but i want it dynamic how could i do this dynamic impelementation?

I have refer apple sample code but in that code also they impelementd hardcode condition.

- Case 1. In Reponse 1 I am getting----(UserLoginComplexType) as
  Rowelement
- Case 2. In Response 2 I am getting----(ctMessageMst xmlns="") as
  Rowelement

  In my Xml parser code I have statically implemented Rowelement name which will not work in Case 2.
  I am not getting idea what to do.

Comment: This is not a normal `XML` data, its `soap service` needs to be handled in different way. Try to find ios with soap, there are many clients available. One I know is http://sudzc.com/ which generates a xcode project with your soap service, and does all the parsing, and handlings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xmlreader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) to parse any complex xml .This will convert complex xml in to dictionary.